# Linux の curl コマンドで接続できない

Tags: centos

Curlコマンドで以下のエラーとなります。ping は通るため、どうしてなのか分かりません。

```
(7) Failed connect to x.x.x.x:80; ホストへの経路がありません
```

状況は下記の通りです。どなたか教えていただけませんでしょうか。

①Centos7を3台デプロイ。各アドレスと下記の通り。
サーバA：10.40.7.33/24　ens224
サーバB：10.40.7.34/24　ens224
サーバC：10.40.7.35/24　ens224

②Ping疎通はお互いに疎通可能。速度なども特に問題無し。

③curlコマンド/firefoxでは自サーバへのアクセスは可能です。
（例えばサーバAで10.40.7.33へcurlコマンドを行うと正常にアクセス可能。）
　
④SE Linuxは一時的に全てpermissiveモードにしている。

Answer (score 1):

firewalld と SELinuxの違いということにお題が変わっていますが。

この２つは全く違うものです。動作するレイヤが異なります。
firewalldはネットワーク（だけ）を対象としています。たとえば特定ポートは閉じておく、特定ポートのアクセスはソースを限定しておくなどの使い方が想定されます。

SELinuxはアプリケーション、プロセス、ファイルのアクセス制御を管理するものです。

⇒誤解を恐れずに言えば、firewalldはNICそれぞれへの制御、SELinuxはOSのリソースそのものの制御をそれぞれになっています。

Webサーバでの動作については、割と[サンプルと解説](https://eng-entrance.com/linux-selinux#SELinuxhttpd)が充実しているので、そちらを参照ください

そのほか以下のようなサイトが参考になります。

https://qiita.com/chi9rin/items/af532d0dd9237cc65741
  https://www.redhat.com/ja/topics/linux/what-is-selinux

Comment: お題が完全に変わってしまった場合は、自己回答の形で Q&A として残し、そちらにリンクする形でコメントするというテクニックがあります。毎回そうすべきとまでは思っていませんが、ひとつのやり方としてコメントに残してみます（ご判断はお任せします）。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。自分に質問して答えるわけですね。
りかいしました。スマートなやり方を教えてくださりありがとうございます。後ほど時間をみて対応します。（忘れていたらごめんなさい。）

Answer (score 0):

問題点はfirewalldでした。SE Linux（=setenforce 0）=firewalldと思い込んでいましたが認識が誤っていました。ここの違いをどなたか補足していただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: "思い込んでいたので違いを…" の部分は別の質問として投稿すべきかと思います。